# Armature Animation not rendering (Blender 2.92)

Tags: animation, armature, keyframes

The armature retains the pose from the first keyframe for the whole animation instead of well, actually animating (i'm rendering the animation image by image so its higher quality).

The file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cgeS1PT1RBATIqh087n6P07D2391EITP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It's pretty hard for us to understand your issue without some more details.  Could you please include a screenshot of what you're working with?

Comment: Yes. Please include screenshots. And share your file. https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Sharing a screenshot would be useless, so i'll just share my file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cgeS1PT1RBATIqh087n6P07D2391EITP/view?usp=sharing